# Adding Lutron 3-way Motion Sensors to Both Switches

Tags: multiway-switch

I purchased two Lutron 3-way switch motion sensor switches and I was surprised that the instructions only suggest using it for one switch. That doesn't make a lot of sense when the other switch is around the corner and would never pick up the motion for the other side. From what I've read it's possible to wire in the second one but I need help.

Here's what the back of the back of the Lutron switch has.

There is a white neutral
There is a blue traveler
There is a black traveler
There is a black hot
There is a ground

Thanks!
[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Some pictures of the existing switches pulled out from the boxes would be helpful. Don't disconnect anything?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring involved please?

Comment: Added some pictures. Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: ThreePhaseEel I'm in San Diego